Using Itô's formula to represent processes without Itô integrals
I am trying to represent the following processes such that they contain no Itô integrals with the help of Itô's formula
$$
X_t = \int_0^t \exp(W_s) dW_s \quad \text{and} \quad Y_t=\int_0^1W_s \exp(W_s^2)dW_s.
$$
The version of Itô's formula that I am supposed to use is the following:
Let $\big(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, (\mathbb{F_t})_{t \in [0, T]}\big)$ be a stochastic basis and $W : [0, T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m$ a m-dimensional standard $\big(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, (\mathbb{F_t})_{t \in [0, T]}\big)$-Brownian motion. Let $T \in (0, \infty)$, $t_0 \in [0, T]$, $t_1 \in [t_0, T]$, $d$, $m$, $v \in \mathbb{N}$, let $O \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open set and $f \in C^2(O, \mathbb{R}^v)$. Furthermore, let $X: [0, T] \times \Omega \to O$ be an Itô process on $\big(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, (\mathbb{F_t})_{t \in [0, T]}\big)$ with drift $Y: [0, T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$, diffusion $Z: [0, T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ and Brownian motion $W$. Then, it holds almost surely
$$f(X_t) = f(X_{t_0}) + \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f'(X_s)Y_s ds + \int_{t_0}^{t_1}f'(X_s)Z_s dW_s + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^m \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f''(X_s) (Z_se_i, Z_se_i)ds,$$
where we define the canonical basis vectors.
$$e_1 := (1, 0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^m, e_2 := (0, 1, 0,\ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^m, \ldots $$
If I'm being honest, I am fairly lost as to how I'm supposed to use Itô's formula. For example, since no drift or diffusion is specified for $X_t$ or $Y_t$ can I choose any arbitrary drift or diffusion? Also, what is $(Z_se_i, Z_se_i)$?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note $e^x=\frac{d}{dx}e^x$ and $xe^{x^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^2}/2)$. Now also note that from Ito's formula for a one-dimensional standard Brownian motion (i.e. dimension $d=1$, zero drift and diffusion coefficient $1$) applied to some $f\in C^2$ we have
$$\int_0^tf'(W_s)dW_s=f(W_t)-f(W_0)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf''(W_s)ds$$
But then, by using $g(x)=e^x,h(x)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}$ we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^te^{W_s}dW_s&=e^{W_t}-1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^te^{W_s}ds\\
\int_0^tW_se^{W_s^2}dW_s&=\frac{e^{W_t^2}-1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t(2W_s^2+1)e^{W_s^2}ds\\
\end{aligned}$$
